# Mixed Content: The page at was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint

Tags: wffm, content-editor

We are having problems loading droplist Name/Value pairs when the datasource is Sitecore items. When I open the WFFM form designer, select the droplist field and choose some items for it I get the following console error:

[image]

error message

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://cms.mydomain.org/sitecore/shell/Applications/Content%20Editor.aspx?sc_bw=1' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://cms.mydomain.org:8003/sitecore/shell/~/xaml/Sitecore.Forms.Shell.UI.Dialogs.ListItemsEditor.aspx?params=%7B048301D3-8A1A-4D3A-ABED-B34782EC3CD9%7D&id=%7B34E80614-F04B-4E8B-8FAD-3E2F48467001%7D&db=master&la=en&vs=1&target=pb_forms_loc_Items&Cart_ctl00_ctl05_ctl00_ctl00_ctl05_ListItems_Callback=yes'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

The CMS server is setup via WebFarms/loadbalancers and is using a valid wildcard domain certificate. Seems like intermediate calls are not being directed to https via loadbalancer ? Anyone seen a similar issue ?

The Sitecore Version is 8.0 (rev. 160115) (8.0 update 7/Service Pack-1)

Comment: Do you have `scheme="https"` attribute set on your `<site>` node in config?

Comment: Does this answer help? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/10427/95 I found that I needed to change the CSP for Chrome to allow the request.

Comment: Are you rewriting your URLs? The intermediary requests won't pick up on the HTTPS since it's probably using the LinkManager to generate the URL. I would look into @jammykam's recommendation above on setting `scheme="https"` on your Sitecore site or use the URL Rewrite module to rewrite all HTTP requests to be HTTPS.

Comment: I added both the scheme="https" and the CSP recommendations as mentioned by @jammykam and Michael West . Now I get the second URL with https but with port number and is timing out. We do have a blank http to https rule setup for all. 'https://cms.mydomain.org:8003/sitecore/shell/~/xaml/Sitecore.Forms.Shell.UI.Dialogs.ListItemsEditor.aspx?params=%7B048301D3-8A1A-4D3A-ABED-B34782EC3CD9%7D&id=%7B34E80614-F04B-4E8B-8FAD-3E2F48467001%7D&db=master&la=en&vs=1&target=pb_forms_loc_Items&Cart_ctl00_ctl05_ctl00_ctl00_ctl05_ListItems_Callback=yes

Comment: Sorry, no idea where that port number is coming from, never seen that issue before. Check your config and make sure it is not specified somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

An absolute address generated on the server is being used instead of a relative address.

You can change this by editing `/sitecore/shell/Applications/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/script/Sitecore.Forms.ListItemsEditor.js`

Adding the following on line 25 before the call to `ListItems.callback`will convert to a relative link

```js
if (ListItems["CallbackPrefix"].indexOf("http") !== -1) {
    var anchor = document.createElement("a");
    anchor.href = ListItems["CallbackPrefix"];
    ListItems["CallbackPrefix"] = anchor.pathname + anchor.search;
    }
```

It looks like this is fixed in Sitecore Experience Platform 8.2 Update-1:

> The Port attribute is now taken into account when links are generated, enabling the configuration of environments with translation ports​​.

from https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/82/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2082%20Update1/Release%20Notes